# Error in enabling a service to start automatically at system reboot

Tags: linux, unix, openldap

I have installed OpenLdap from an external tar file on my Redhat Linux server(not from default rpm package). After that I started the service `/usr/local/sbin/slapd` successfully. This service needs a environment variable to be set:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/root/db-6.0.20/build_unix/.libs"
```

so that all necessary library files are available to the service. However I want that the service is enabled to restart automatically at system reboot. I created a softlink to the service `/usr/local/sbin/slapd` under `/etc/init.d`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Aug  5 14:34 slapd -> /usr/local/sbin/slapd
```

when i am trying to check doing `service slapd restart` its showing the below error:

```
[root@dgseir init.d]# service slapd restart
/etc/init.d/slapd: error while loading shared libraries: libdb-6.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

As a result of this i am not able to set the runlevels for this using `chkconfig`. However , the service is running fine from its absolute path `/usr/local/sbin/slapd` as i have set the necessary environment variable in `.bash_profile`

Kindly help to eradicate the problem, or let me know any other way to enable service to restart automatically at server restart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, i would advice you from using LD_LIBRARY_PATH or LD_PRELOAD tricks for system services.
instead you should *properly* install all required libraries.
doing so, will automatically solve your problems with not being able to find `libdb-6.0.so` (since the .so file will be installed into `/usr/local/lib/`)

but you have a conceptual problem as well.

the files in `/etc/init.d` are *scripts* that control daemons according to some standard interface.
e.g. the following will start the *foo* daemon

```
/etc/init.d/foo start
```

whereas this will stop it:

```
/etc/init.d/foo stop
```

in most cases the actual daemon binary, will have completely different syntax. e.g. the *slapd* daemon really will be running as something like the following:

```
/usr/local/sbin/slapd -h ldap:/// ldaps:/// \
                      -g openldap -u openldap \
                      -F /etc/ldap/slapd.d
```

the `/etc/init.d/slapd` *script* will take care of calling the binary `/usr/local/sbin/slapd` with the correct arguments (and terminate it, when called with the `stop` argument).

this basically means, that you cannot simply create a symlink from `/etc/init.d/slapd` to `/usr/local/sbin/slapd`; these two are different programs with different tasks.

there should be an example init.d script on your system as `/etc/init.d/skeleton` (at least this is the case on Debian; i don't know about Redhat). take a look at this example. adopt it to your needs (you will find that you *could* set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable in the script)

Comment: Thanks for clearing the concept

Answer (score -1):

Before starting 1st export the shared library.

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/path-to-required-library`

for e.g if your library in /home/use/lsap/lib

`e.g export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/use/lsap/lib`

Comment: As I have explained, this has already been defined in the `.bash_profile` so no need to export again. Sorry couldn't find my answer...

Comment: for completeness sake: whatever you do in *your* (e.g. some users') `.bash_profile`, will have zero effect on other users (e.g. `root` who is running init.d-scripts). furthermore, `.bash_profile` is only read when `bash` is started as an interactive shell (as `man bash` will tell you) - which is not the case when the system starts the init.d daemons.